# Python datetime timedelta issue

Tags: python, date, datetime, timedelta, python-datetime

I am trying to set the predict_day variable to either the current date if the time from the timems datetime is between 0:00:00 and 9:29:59.
 If the time is between 9:30:00 and 15:59:59, I want to continue to the next item.
If the time is between 16:00:00 and 23:59:59 I want to add one day to the day_predict using timedelta(days=1) where timems.weekday() = 0, 1, 2, 3.
 When timems.weekday() = 4, and time is between 16:00:00 and 23:59:59, I need day_predict to add 3 days by using timedelta(days=3).
 When timems.weekday() = 5 no matter the time, I need day_predict to add 2 days uisng itmedelta(days=2).
 When timems.weekday() = 6 no matter the time, I need day_predict to add 1 day.

```
# Format Datetime Stamps
timems = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(item['TimeMs']['$numberLong']) / 1e3)
time = timems.time()
hour = time.hour
minute = time.minute
second = time.second

# Sets predict_day to current day if tweet occurred between 12am and 930am
if timems.weekday() == 0 or timems.weekday() == 1 or timems.weekday() == 2 or timems.weekday() == 3 or timems.weekday() == 4 and (datetime.time(0,0,0) <= datetime.time(hour, minute, second) and datetime.time(hour, minute, second) <= datetime.time(9,29,59)):
    predict_day = timems.date()
# Sets predict_day to current day + 1 if tweet occurred between 4pm and 12am on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday
if timems.weekday() == 0 or timems.weekday() == 1 or timems.weekday() == 2 or timems.weekday() == 3 and (datetime.time(15,59,59) <= datetime.time(hour, minute, second) and datetime.time(hour, minute, second) <= datetime.time(23,59,59)):
    predict_day = timems.date() + datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
# Sets perdict_day to current day + 3 (Monday) if tweet occurerd after 4pm on Friday
if timems.weekday() == 4 and (datetime.time(15,59,59) <= datetime.time(hour, minute, second) and datetime.time(hour, minute, second) <= datetime.time(23,59,59)):
    predict_day = timems.date() + datetime.timedelta(days = 3)
# Sets predict_day to current day + 2 (Monday) if tweet occurred on Saturday
if timems.weekday() == 5 and (datetime.time(0,0,0) <= datetime.time(hour, minute, second) or datetime.time(hour, minute, second) <= datetime.time(23,59,59)):
    predict_day = timems.date() + datetime.timedelta(days = 2)
# Sets predict_day to current day + 1 (Monday) if tweet occured on Sunday
if timems.weekday() == 6 and (datetime.time(0,0,0) <= datetime.time(hour, minute, second) or datetime.time(hour, minute, second) <= datetime.time(23,59,59)):
    predict_day = timems.date() + datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
```

My results are being written to a .csv file and I am having issues getting it to run correctly.

Comment: "I am having issues getting it to run correctly." Okay... so? What problem specifically are you having, improper output, error message, ect?

Comment: Improper output specifically with Fridays, Saturdays, and Sundays

Comment: Please update your question to show what you are getting along with desired output